# Smart constructor for tuple in Idris

Tags: haskell, idris

I started reading Chapter 6 of "Type-driven development with Idris" and attempted to write a smart constructor for a tupled vector.

```
TupleVect : Nat -> Type -> Type
TupleVect Z _ = ()
TupleVect (S k) a = (a, TupleVect k a)

someValue : TupleVect 4 Nat
someValue = (1,2,3,4,())

TupleVectConstructorType : Nat -> Type -> Type
TupleVectConstructorType n typ = helper n
  where
    helper : Nat -> Type
    helper Z = TupleVect n typ
    helper (S k) = typ -> helper k

tupleVect : (n : Nat) -> (a : Type) -> TupleVectConstructorType n a
tupleVect Z a = ()
tupleVect (S Z) a = \val => (val, ())
tupleVect (S (S Z)) a = \val2 => \val1 => (val2, val1, ())
-- ??? how to create tupleVect (S k) a
```

How to create a constructor for an arbitrary k?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically @Matthias Berndt's idea. Counting down the arrows to be added, while making the final tuple longer. For this we need to access the more permissive helper from `TupleVectType`.

```
TupleVectType' : Nat -> Nat -> Type -> Type
TupleVectType' Z n a = TupleVect n a
TupleVectType' (S k) n a = a -> TupleVectType' k (S n) a

TupleVectType : Nat -> Type -> Type
TupleVectType n = TupleVectType' n Z

tupleVect : (n : Nat) -> (a : Type) -> TupleVectType n a
tupleVect n a = helper n Z a ()
    where
        helper : (k, n : Nat) -> (a : Type) -> (acc : TupleVect n a)
            -> TupleVectType' k n a
        helper Z n a acc = acc
        helper (S k) n a acc = \x => helper k (S n) a (x, acc)

someValue2 : TupleVect 4 Nat
someValue2 = (tupleVect 4 Nat) 4 3 2 1
```

Though note that this will result in `\v2 => \v1 => (v1, v2, ())` and not `\v2 => \v1 => (v2, v1, ())` as the former fits the recursive definition of `TupleVect (S k) a = (a, TupleVect k a)` better.

Comment: Nice solution. But it should be possible to simplify it.
`helper` doesn't need the `a` type parameter, because you can just use the `a` from the enclosing scope. Same goes for `TupleVectType'`, which you can just declare in `tupleVect`'s `where` clause. 

Then there's `k` in `helper`. If you rename the `n` variable in `tupleVect` to `m`, then `k` is just `m - n` and thus redundant. Unfortunately I just couldn't get the code to compile after making these changes :-/

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt `a` is indeed redundant. `TupleVectType'` needs to be explicit so `helper` can access it. Using `m - n` should be `minus m n` so you don't have to deal with the `LTE` proof, but you would still have to deal with other proofs and some `rewrite`s, so that the variant with `k` is just simpler to type (in the keyboard and the type system sense :-)), albeit not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I know almost nothing about Idris except that it's a dependently-typed, Haskell-like language. But I find this problem intriguing, so I gave it a shot.

Clearly you need a recursive solution here. My idea is to use an additional parameter `f` which accumulates the `val1`..`val_n` parameters that the function has eaten so far. When the base case is reached, `f` is returned.

```
tupleVectHelper Z a f = f
tupleVectHelper (S n) a f = \val => tupleVectHelper n a (val, f)

tupleVect n a = tupleVectHelper n a ()
```

I have no idea if this works, and I haven't yet figured out how to write the type of `tupleVectHelper`, but I've tried doing the substitutions manually for `n = 3` and it does seem to work out on paper, though the resulting tuple is backwards. But I think that shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Hope this helps!